# void netif_napi_add

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

the syntax for netif_napi_add is

```
netif_napi_add(struct net_device *dev, struct napi_struct *napi,int (*poll)(struct napi_struct *, int), int weight)
```

it is used for initializing the napi structure . the problem is when i am using the function as

```
 netif_napi_add(wdev,rnapi,rrpoll(rnapi,20),16);
```

its giving me warning on time of compilation as

```
warning: passing argument 3 of ‘netif_napi_add’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/src/linux-2.6.34.10-0.6/include/linux/netdevice.h:1089:6: note: expected ‘int (*)(struct napi_struct *, int)’ but argument is of type ‘int’
```

how to write it correctly ??

regards

karan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the call

```
netif_napi_add(wdev,rnapi,rrpoll(rnapi,20),16);
```

you are *calling* `rrpoll`. It should be passed as a pointer:

```
netif_napi_add(wdev,rnapi,&rrpoll,16);
```

The system will then call `rrpoll` for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the call

```
netif_napi_add(wdev,rnapi,rrpoll(rnapi,20),16);
```

U can use rrpoll instead of passing the whole function.
i.e

```
netif_napi_add(wdev,rnapi,rrpoll,16);
```